# Can anyone please tell me why it is called Parametric equation?

Tags: terminology, conic-sections, parametrization

**Parametric representation** of the parabola $y^2 = x$  is $(t^2 , t)$.

Can anyone please tell me why it is called Parametric representation ?

Can I say $(x , \pm \sqrt x)$  is a parametric representation of $y^2 = x$ ?

I know for a family of equations for every value of parameter we get a particular member  of that family.

$x^2+y^2 = a^2$  is the family of circles with center at origin. If we put $a= 1$ , we get a particular circle. $a$ is also varying but for a particular value of $a$ we are getting a member. That is why , this is little different from variable.

Answer (score 2):

As with any language, mathematics is allowed to use the same word for different notions.

- One sense of "parameter" (the second in the question) is that of "characteristic" or perhaps "ingredient"; a value that helps describe or define an object. Like how the *parameters of a debate* define the scope of topics that can be discussed. So, parameters can include the radius and/or center of a circle, the aspect ratio of a rectangle, the $x$- and $y$-intercepts of a line. The ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics" pages](https://jeff560.tripod.com/p.html) mention that "parameter" was first used in 1631 specifically for the latus rectum of a conic.
- The "parametric equation" sense of "parameter" is that of "other measurement", in particular with regard to graphing curves and surfaces. (See [this ancient answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/485482/409) to the question ["What is a the intuition behind a parametric equation?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/485407/409).) Sticking with curves ... While we often graph by expressing $y$ in terms of $x$, or $x$ in terms of $y$, there are significant advantages (beyond the scope of discussion here) to expressing *both* $x$ and $y$ in terms of *something else* ---an "other measurement", or *parameter*--- that helps convey a graph as a *path of travel*. Whereas the cartesian equation $x^2+y^2=1$ for the unit circle is perfectly effective at defining a static *set of points*, the parametric forms $(\cos t,\sin t)$ and $\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)$ describe (very) different dynamic *journeys* along the curve.

So, the $a$ in $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and the $t$ in $(t,t^2)$ are both *parameters*, but in different senses of the word. (Attempts to fashion a single meaning to the term that covers both use cases are a bit strained.)

Consequently, we have the situation that $(a\cos t, b\sin t)$ uses the *parameter* $t$ to traverse an elliptical path defined by *parameters* (namely, semi-axes) $a$ and $b$. Language is funny like that sometimes. (See ["Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).)

---

As to whether $(x,\pm \sqrt{x})$ can be considered a parametric representation of parabola $x=y^2$ ...

It's a not-unreasonable *representation* of the parabola, in the same way as one writes $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$. It tells you something about the points on the curve. So, fine.

However, $(x,\pm\sqrt{x})$ doesn't describe a *path of travel* along the curve; rather, at each $x$, an ostensible traveler either chooses between candidate $y$-values, or somehow visits both of them simultaneously. That defeats the purpose of describing a *path*. A *proper* "parametric representation" doesn't give a choice; the value of the parameter should tell you *exactly* where you are. Formally: the $x$ and $y$ coordinates should be *functions* of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A parameter is one or more numbers that is varied to give a collection of "things". Each value of the parameter(s) should give a single thing. For instance,

- In $(t,t^2)$, the parameter $t$ can be varied to give a collection of points
- In $x^2+y^2=a^2$, the parameter $a$ can be varied to give a collection of circles
- In $\displaystyle\frac1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac12\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^2}$, the two parameters $\sigma$ and $\mu$ can be varied to give different distribution functions for different normal distributions

In the case where the collection of things is a collection of points in the plane, or in higher dimensional space, then we call that a parametric representation of that collection of points. Because we use a parameter to represent them.

Comment: Can I say $(x , \pm \sqrt x)$  a parametric representation ? @Arthur

Comment: @sani It's not conventional. Usually, one value of $x$ should give a _single_ point in the plane.

Answer (score 1):

The idea with a parametric equation (with a single real parameter) is that it "draws the curve" as you vary the parameter.

For the parabola $y^2=x$, your attempt $(x,\pm\sqrt x)$ makes sense, but multi-valued expressions like $\pm...$ aren't allowed. This would "draw two curves at once" as $x$ moves through positive values (and draw nothing when $x$ is negative). In contrast, the parametrization $(t^2,t)$ gives a clean one-to-one correspondence (in fact a [homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)) between the parameter space $\Bbb R$ and the parabola.

$x^2+y^2=a^2$ is an equation with a parameter that describes a family of circles, and positive values of $a$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the members of the family. But since it's not a family of *points*, I probably wouldn't call it a parametric equation.

Answer (score 0):

It is called a parametric equation, because we can relate the values of x and y (or even z, if we consider a 3-D space) to a single parameter (let's call it t).

Consider the example you gave, of the parabola $y^{2}=x$. We can relate the values of x and y, by a single parameter t, which gives the value of x and y, as the parameter changes, both x and y change also, such that it satisfies the original equation.

And no, the example you gave isn't a parametric equation because it doesn't satisfy the original equation.

Comment: Relating the values of $x , y$ to $t$. Therefore , $t$ is parameter. Then why $a$ is the parameter in the family of circles $x^2+y^2 = a^2$ ?@Ishraaq Parvez