# *Seeing* why horizontal shifts are reversed?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I know it's true, and understand why, but I can't *see* it. I feel stupid.

Perhaps I can't *see* it becaus too complex to hold at once, the two functions, the translation, the axes. Maybe it's not important to "see" it anyway, and I'm expecting too much... and knowing the rule and why is enough?

**What** If we start with function $f(x)$, then shift it vertically by $\Delta y$ and horizonally by $\Delta x$, to get another function $g(x)$, then

$$ g(x) = f(x - \Delta x) + \Delta y $$

Although we add $\Delta y$, we *subtract* $\Delta x$ - this subtraction is the "reverse" of the question.

**Why** One way to think about it is that $g$ is sampling $f$ at another input point.  To get to that other point, from the point of view of $g$, we go backwards, the opposite direction. When we describe $f$ being shifted to become $g$, it is from the point of view of $f$. So, this change in point of view is why we reverse the horizontal shift. If instead, we described the shift as where we came from, it would already be "reversed".

This creates another puzzle: why isn't $\Delta y$ reversed too? Because it's a translation of the output, after the change in point of view has already occurred.

In another way, the difference between horizonal and vertical translation is an artefact of notation. They are both reversed (or, from the point of view of the new function), if notated as:

$$ g(x) - \Delta y = f(x - \Delta x)$$

**Seeing** It seems simpler to just follow the evaluation of the function. For $ g(x)  = f(x + a) + b$, first you add $a$, then evaluate $f$ there, and finally add $b$. There's an extra layer of cognition when *interpreting* this as a translation of $f$ to $g$, because it entails a change in frame of reference (from $g$'s POV to $f$'s POV).

I think my confusion of this comes from how it was taught: instead of begining with function evaluation and then how it can be seen *as* a translation, we were taught the tramslation as a thing in itself, using the "rule" above. An "explanation" was given as an afterthought, secondary to the "rule". I'm not convinced the teacher had any real understanding beyond that, so they couldn't pass on an underetanding beyond the rule.

Comment: The graph of $g(x)=f(x-a)$ is the set of points of the form $(x,f(x-a))$, while the graph of $f(x)$ is the set of points of the form $(x,f(x))$. But the former set is precisely the same as the set of points of the form $(x+a,f(x))$, which are just the points on the graph of $f(x)$ shifted $a$ units to the right. (By contrast, the points on the graph of $g(x)=f(x)+a$ are of the form $(x,f(x)+a)$, which are just the points $(x,f(x))$ shifted $a$ upward.)

Comment: @symplectomorphic great approach, using a more formal description of "shift". Can I request you write it as an answer, so I can accept it? I found it intimidating at first. I think it would ease a reader into the concept, by starting first with `the graph of f(x) is the set of points of the form (x,f(x))`, and omitting the vertical translation part, just to keep it simple (even though it's true). I've *long* been confused by this, so an extremely simple and direct answer would really help. Sorry to be so picky and annoying!

Comment: [Here's my "Function Monkey" description from a few years back.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133417/409) (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1744/409) for an introduction to the Function Monkey himself.) After all this time, I see that I should probably streamline it (and perhaps add some actual images of coconuts) ... someday ...

Comment: @ symplectomorphic  @ hyperpallium

Comment: @ symplectomorphic  @ hyperpallium   Thanks for all this!  I think the key point is to understand why the set of points ( x , f(x-a) is identical to the set of points    (x+a, f(x) ). Is there any simple algebraic proof of this? - I recently tried to answer the same question as this post and to provide a visual explanation, unfortunately I'm really bad at graphing as you'll see if you go to : " Is this visual explanation of horizontal shifting helpfull ( if not beautifull...)?  "

Comment: @RayLittleRock let's use different variables: $(y, f(y-a))$ and $(z+a,f(z))$. Now let's say they are related as $y=z+a$. Subbing into the first gives the second. But I have to say, I still have trouble with all this.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, lets assume $A>1,B>1,\Delta x>0$, and $\Delta y>0$. I like to think of the transformation $$g(x)=A\cdot f(B\cdot (x+\Delta x))+\Delta y\qquad (*)$$ as the composition $g(x)=V(f(H(x))$, where

- $H(x)=B\cdot(x+\Delta x)$ is a linear transformation done on the inputs *before* they are fed into $f$ (a so-called "horizontal" transformation), and
- $V(y)=A\cdot y+\Delta y$ is a linear transformation done on the outputs *after* they are produced by $f$ (a so-called "vertical" transformation).

More explicitly, given a set $\mathcal{D}\subset\mathbb{R}$, the set $H(\mathcal{D})=B\cdot(\mathcal{D}+\Delta x)$ is obtained by first shifting $\mathcal{D}$ to the *right* by $\Delta x$ to get the set $\mathcal{D}+\Delta x$, then *enlarging* that by a factor of $B$. Then the set $H(\mathcal{D})$ is passed into $f$, by which $f(H(\mathcal{D}))$ is produced. Finally, $$g(\mathcal{D})=V(f(H(\mathcal{D})))=A\cdot f(H(\mathcal{D}))+\Delta y$$ is obtained by *enlarging* $f(H(\mathcal{D}))$ by a factor of $A$ to obtain $A\cdot f(H(\mathcal{D}))$, then shifting that to the *right* by $\Delta y$ (notice I did not say "up" because we regard $f(H(\mathcal{D}))$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$).

So far everything has followed the order of operations, and $A,B>1$ correspond to enlargement and $\Delta x,\Delta y>0$ correspond to shifting in the positive direction. Note that in the special case that $f$ is invertible, one can write $g^{-1}$ in the same form as $(*)$: $$g^{-1}(y)=\frac{1}{B}\cdot f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{A}\cdot(y-\Delta y)\right)-\Delta x.$$ As it should, this function applies all of the inverse steps to the set of $y$ values in the opposite order: shift the set of all $y$ values left by $\Delta y$, then shrink the set by a factor of $1/A$, then feed it through $f^{-1}$, shrink the image by $1/B$, then shift it left by $\Delta x$. This reveals the "symmetry" between the before/after linear transformations (this at least cleared up some confusion I used to have about why $A\cdot y+\Delta y$ and $B\cdot(x+\Delta x)$ were distributed differently).

However, I think the real source of the confusion is how all of this transformation is manifested on an $xy$-graph. I think this is because the graph compares the *domain* of $x$ values to the *codomain* of $y$ values, though the "symmetry" we saw above is actually between the *domain* and *image* of $f$. For example, we are familiar with the function $f(x)=\sin{x}$, its domain and image, and its graph. The way I was originally told to understand the graph of, say, $$g(x)=4\sin{3(x+2)}+1,$$ was to apply this sequence of transformations to the graph of $f$:

1. Horizontally shrink the *graph* by a factor of $\frac{1}{B}=\frac{1}{3}$,
2. Shift the *graph* left by $\Delta x=2$,
3. Vertically enlarge the *graph* by a factor of $A=4$,
4. Shift the *graph* up by $\Delta y=1$.

Though this gives the correct pictorial result, the "true" sequence is

1. Shift the *domain* right by $\Delta x=2$,
2. Then stretch the *domain* by a factor of $B=3$, (now feed this transformed domain into $f$)
3. Vertically enlarge the *image* of $f$ by a factor of $A=4$,
4. Shift the *image* up by $\Delta y=1$.

In both sequences, the last two steps (the vertical transformations) are the same because both represent transformations of the *image* of $f$ (not the codomain!). Steps 1. and 2. in the first sequence obscure/hide the fact that it is the *domain* that is being changed. In other words, the images of the two functions $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $f(H(x))=\sin(3(x+2))$ are exactly the same, though their domains have been transformed.

So, very long story short: Think in terms of *domain* and *image*.

**Exercise:** Find and compare the fibers $f^{-1}(1)$ and $(f\circ H)^{-1}(1)$. How are these fibers explicitly related by $H$?

Answer (score 0):

First note that if you think of $g(x)$ as $y$, then you've written

$$y-\Delta y = f(x-\Delta x).$$

So when you put the increments next to their parent variables, *both* are, in fact, subtracted.

Second, as to why subtracting moves things to the right, well, you've slowed $x$ down by $\Delta x$, so everything $f(x)$ does, $f(x-\Delta x)$ does *later* and "later" means further to the right.