# Is this visual explanation of horizontal shifting at least helpful ? ( ...if not beautiful...)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

With  the  image below I try to explain in which way substituting (x-a) 
( with a> 0) for x in the expression defining a function results in a shift to the right, although " intuition" tells us it should result in a shift to the left. To do this I use the auxiliary idea of "shifting" as "copying" or "imitating".

I would be interested in knowing whether this explanation could be efficient in the classroom at the high school level.

Suppose we have $y=f(x)=x^2$ and want to graph $y=g(x)=f(x-1).$

The function $g$ maps each $x$ to the image of $(x-1)$ under the function $f$.

In other words, each  $x$ value has an "$ x-1$ " ( his own  "$x-1$" ) , and
copies his (x-1) 's image under the "old" mapping $f$ .

Since each "imitator" ( each $x$ value) is to the RIGHT of it's "model", that is it's " $x-1 $" , the change from the function  $f(x)=x^2$  to the function  $ g(x)=f(x-1)$  results , for each "old" point of the graph of f, in a translation of $1$ unit to the RIGHT.

[image]

Remark. - I first used the idea of " stealing" , for which I substitute the idea of " copying" or "imitating". I've just seen a post of Hyperpallium using the idea of " sampling" , even better.

Link to Hyperpallium's post : [*Seeing* why horizontal shifts are reversed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813164/seeing-why-horizontal-shifts-are-reversed)

Comment: This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133185/explaining-horizontal-shifting-and-scaling) is a good post explaining this concept, because at the moment your explanation is overcomplicating the situation quite alot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about teaching mathematics (Math Educators SE) and not based on an understand, or lack thereof, of various mathematical fields.

Comment: @ Hushus46 . Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it moves the whole plane by 1 in x dimension. I would like to call it *swiping* instead of stealing. Nothing is taken, it's just shuffled around a bit.

Imagine swiping a whole image on a mobile phone screen 1 step right but none in up-down direction.

It is a good insight. First step towards geometric transformations, rotations, projections.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion is nothing deeper than this:

[image]

Ignore all the confusing suggestions about "stealing."  Certainly not helpful.  Certainly not beautiful.

Comment: This drawing is self explanatory. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm.... not even an upvote?